# How to know what content a character variable contains?

Tags: java

Now if i need to print "alphabets" if the character contains alphabets , need to print "number" if the character contains number.
sorry if the questions seems silly, new to java.

Using charAt() function i've converted the string to characters, all i need is to find the content of the chararcter.

Comment: `Character.isDigit(char)` should do it.

Comment: A) do you talk about a single char value? Or a string? B) please include your own efforts of doing your homework. This is not a place where you drop you assignment and then others do the work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code :

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str ="abc123"; 
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) ? "number" : "alphabet");
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
alphabet
alphabet
alphabet
number
number
number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i got my concepts clear now

Answer (score 0):

`String.contains` might be you're looking for.

```java
String str = "abc";
boolean isAlphabet = str.contains("a"); // is true
boolean isNumber = str.contains("1"); // is false
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your input string to below snippet, if its number then it will return true if its alphabets then it returns false

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another alternative is to use regular expression

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    return strNum.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}
```